# How is the limit $\lim_{x\to 3^+} \frac{1}{(x-3)^2}$ $+\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How $$\lim_{x\to 3^+} \frac{1}{(x-3)^2}$$ positive infinity?
I did L'Hopital rule, got top as $0$ and denominator as $2(x-3)$, and plugged in $3$, so still got $0/0$. Isn't that DNE? And since we cannot differentiate it anymore?

Comment: You cannot use L'Hopital rule...

Comment: ... because it's not an indeterminate expression.

Comment: this is supposed to be one of the fundamental limit's
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 3^+}\Big(\frac{1}{x-3}\Big)^2 = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+}\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)^2=+\infty$ using $(t=x-3)$

Comment: Did you, just maybe, try what happens when you let x = 3.1, 3.01, 3.001, 3.0001 using a pocket calculator, spreadsheet, or just doing it in your head? That might have given you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use L'Hôpital's rule to evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ if **both** numerator and denominator converge to $0$ (or both to $\pm\infty$, respectively).

Your fraction converges to $+\infty$ because $(x-3)^2$ converges to $0$ *from the positive side* as $x$ converges to $3$.

This is only the mathematical way of saying that the reciprocal of a *really small positive number* is a *really large positive number*!

Comment: then what could I have done here and how is the answer positive infinity?

Comment: Think about it, if $x$ comes close to three, then $x-3$ is very close to $0$, so also $(x-3)^2$ is close to zero (but positive!), so $1/(x-3)^2$ gets a very large *positive* number!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use l'Hospital rule, because there is no indetermination.

$$\lim_{x\to 3^+}\frac{1}{(x-3)^2}=\lim_{u\to 0^+}\frac{1}{u^2}=+\infty .$$

Comment: so is 1/0 infinity?

Comment: $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined.

Comment: It's not $\frac{1}{0}$ but $\frac{1}{0^+}$ which is defined and gives $+\infty $.

Comment: And actually, $\frac{1}{0}$ is defined too and gives $+\infty $ in $0^+$ and $-\infty $ in $0^-$.